# Recommend a book that teaches fact versus opinion

Tags: critical-thinking

I would like to find a book or some reliable source that explains how to teach the difference between a fact and an opinion. I would like this to appeal to as many people as possible, many ages, many backgrounds, and so on. So I have in mind something simple and direct. I thought there might be something elementary with which to start a discussion, but I'm uncertain where to look in the ocean of information.

It's been decades since I was in graduate school, so I'm not going to recount everything I've read. Recent attempts to answer this question have included asking teachers I know, doing an internet search for "fact", what is a fact, and what is the difference between a fact and an opinion; reading How to Think by Alan Jacobs and parts of The Portable Handbook of Critical Thinking by Richard Epstein. I found an entry for "fact" at the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy at plato.stanford.edu which is fairly complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently turn to Timothy Williamson's "I'm Right, You're Wrong" when teaching this distinction. It's a four-way debate between a scientist, logician, relativist, and layperson who happen to be stuck on a train together. Check out [this review](https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/tetralogue-i-m-right-you-re-wrong/) for more information, if you're interested.